# Jquery only loading after the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have built a web application, which has few pages and on the home page needs to retrieve the data from API and it works fine but suppose when I click on another page and then from that I click  back on the home page it doesn't load that get API request until I refresh the page!i tried pagecreate,load,ready but it doesn't work!

you can check the website https://woke-agency.com
Here's my code now

```
$(document.body).ready(()=>{
const LoadWorks = () => {
    //api here
}

LoadWorks("/api/works/")
})
```

Comment: I think we need a little bit more information. With this information it seems that the navigation happens without load another url, so when returns to the home (in the same window) "ready" not fires again because was ready first time. Hope this help. Good luck.

Comment: It helped! Actually it was loading the page in a different manner with the help of javascript in background,thanks!

Comment: you welcome Morgan.